# Como puedo realizar operaciones con mi variable $res que es el valor de una opcion del select que vine de la base de datos?

Tags: jquery, base-de-datos

Necesito que se convierta en un valor numerico para hacer las operaciones, por que cuando hago una operacion me sale un error que dice que el no es un dato numerico y tambien quisiera saber si esta bien obrenido el dato.
Necesito hacer operaciones con estos valores ya que es un cotizador y esos son son los valores de cada opcion que depende que obtenga el cliente lo ocupare para poder obtener mi resultado total

```
           
   <h2> Sube Tu Cuota </h2>

    <?php 
        $query = "SELECT DISTINCT nombre, usuarios FROM sistema "; 
        $res = $conexion->query($query);
        $option = '';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $option .= "<option value=\"$row[nombre]\">$row[nombre] </option>" ; 
        } 
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="insertar.php">
        <input type="text" name="com" placeholder="comentarios">
            <select name="shape" >
                <option value=""> Select a shape </option>
                <?php echo $option; ?> 

            </select>
            
            <input type="submit" name="registrar">
            <input type="submit" value="consultar" name="btn-2">
    </form>
    <?php 
    
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `sistemascomentarios` SC JOIN `sistema` S ON SC.idSistema = S.idSistema ";
        $res = $conexion->query($query);
        $table ='<tr>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            $table ='<p>';
            $table .= "<td>$row[usuarios]</td>";
            $table .='</tr>';
        }
        
        $table .='</p>';

        $res = $table ;
       
    ?>

    <tr>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
        
        <?php echo $res ;
        ?> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿QUé valor necesitas que sea numérico? ¿Dónde lo estás usando (cuál es la operación matemática donde falla)?

Comment: Estoy probando por el momento con una suma, la variable que quiero que sea numerica es la "$res", falla cuando pongo una suma para comprobar y me sale este error Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in, ahi esta el codigo de la parte que intento probar la operacion   `     $table .='</p>';

        $res = $table ;
   
      
    ?>

    <tr>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
        
        <?php    

     
        $result =($res + 1);
        echo $result; 
        ?>
  `